# How to use a VueJS component as a CSS grid items container?

Tags: vuejs2, css-grid

In my parent component, I have a **grid container** and a child component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <grid-items></grid-items>
      <grid-items></grid-items>
      <grid-items></grid-items>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The child component contains **grid items**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="item">FOO</div>
    <div class="item">BAR</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

It doesn't work because I have to surround the **grid-items** with an extra root `div` in the child component, breaking the grid logic. If I remove this surrounding `div` in the child component, I get the following compilation error message:

> Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are
>   using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

How can I fix this CSS grid logic issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cant, i would do it like this:

```
<template>
 <div>
   <grid-items></grid-items>
 </div>
```

And put the container instead in your child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">FOO</div>
    <div class="item">BAR</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Otherwise you will need to make for every grid item 1 component

Comment: I can't do it because the grid may contain more than one child component (or group of items). I clarified my post after yours.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using [vue-fragments](https://github.com/y-nk/vue-fragment) plugin thanks to [this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/09/11/vue-multiple-root-fragments/) great article. Below is how I used it.

1. Install the plugin

```
npm i -s vue-fragment
```

2. Load it globally in `app.js`

```
import Fragment from 'vue-fragment';
Vue.use(Fragment.Plugin);
```

3. Create **parent** component `grid-container.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <grid-items></grid-items>
    <grid-items></grid-items>
  </div>
</template>
```

4. Create **child** component `grid-items.vue`

```
<template>
  <fragment>
    <div>FOO</div>
    <div>BAR</div>
  </fragment>
</template>
```